# Proving that $x(1-e^{-1/x})$ is strictly increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, contest-math

Prove that the function below is strictly increasing
$$f(x)=x(1-e^{-1/x}), \quad x>0$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Letting $y=-\frac1x$ we see that 
$$ f(x) = \frac{e^y-1}{y}$$
is the slope of the secant line through $(0,e^0)$ and $(y,e^y)$.
The claim then follows from the convexity of the exponential.

Comment: Only nice answers here. Thanks! (+1)

Comment: This is nice. I can visualize the transformed function and the secant line in my head. +1.

Comment: Really nice! So simple!

Comment: Yeah, it's a very beautiful math piece!

Answer (score 10):

If $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$, then $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is strictly decreasing.
$$ 
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( \frac{1-\exp(-x)}{x} \right) = \mathrm{e}^{-x} \frac{1+x-\mathrm{e}^{x}}{x} < 0
$$ 
The last inequality is consequence of the well known $\mathrm{e}^x > 1+x$ valid for $x>0$.

Comment: hehe, nice. Actually this answer is really awesome. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If $x<0$ and $x>y$ then $-x,-y$ are positive and $-1/x>-1/y$ and so $\exp(-1/x)>\exp(-1/y)$ and then $1-\exp(-1/x)<1-\exp(-1/y)$ and so $$-x(1-e^{-1/x})<-x(1-e^{-1/y})<-y(1-e^{-1/y})$$ this shows that when $x<0$, then $x>y\to f(x)>f(y)$.

Comment: Nice! This seem rather elementary! Thanks (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: Yes, it is very elementary as I am. Thanks for sharing great questions, always.

Comment: Glad to see around so many approaching ways. :-)

Comment: +1 I really like how often you offer alternative perspectives and approaches. It helps us all (the asker and users alike) "think outside the box".

Comment: @amWhy: Usually, I think of the simple way for the problem and unexpectedly the way is true. I wish, I could think of the problem globally as others did. Anyway, thanks. ;-)

Comment: But that's a good thing: simplification of a problem, rather than "overkill" when not necessary. Sometimes people offer answers that are beyond the level of the asker. And you are so humble (I admire this quality), but you underestimate your level of contribution and expertise.

Comment: This does not work. $y<0$ implies (1-e^{-1/y})<0$, hence the second inequality must be reversed.

Comment: The second inequality is certainly not true as @ziggurism pointed out. If you select x=-1 and y=-2 you showed something like $-1.7183<-0.6487<-1.2974$.

Comment: @obareey The inequality required is ultimately an expression of the convexity of the exponential. So it would have been very surprising if Mikasa has been able to prove it using only monotonicity. I'm not sure how to formalize the intuition about which axiomatic facts of the exponential function are required for which results, but that's my intuition.