# Does this definition of $e$ even make sense?

Tags: calculus, definition, exponential-function

This sprung from a conversation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734853/differentiate-sqrt1ex-using-the-definition-of-a-derivative?noredirect=1#comment3540676_1734853). In Stewart's Calculus textbook, he defined $e$ as the unique solution to $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}=1$. Ahmed asked how do you define $x^h$ is not by $\exp(h\ln(x))$ and I'm not sure.

Does this definition of $e$ even make sense?

Definition here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $e$ as the unique number such that $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{h} - 1}{h} = 1$$ makes sense, but there are few points which must be established before this definition can be used:

1. Define the general power $a^{x}$ for all $a > 0$ and all real $x$. One approach is to define it as the limit of $a^{x_{n}}$ where $x_{n}$ is a sequence of rational numbers tending to $x$ (this is not so easy).
2. Based on the definition of $a^{x}$ above show that the limit $(a^{x} - 1)/x$ as $x \to 0$ exists for all $a > 0$ (this is hard) and hence the limit defines a functions $f(a)$ for $a > 0$.
3. The function $f(x)$ defined above is continuous, strictly increasing and maps $(0, \infty)$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$ (easy if previous points are established).

From the last point above it follows that there is a unique number $e > 1$ such that $f(e) = 1$. This is the definition of $e$ with which we started. And as can be seen this definition must be preceded by the proof of the results mentioned in three points above. All this is done in [my blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html) and in my opinion this is the most difficult route to a theory of exponential and logarithmic functions. Easier routes to the theory of exponential and logarithmic functions are covered in [this post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html) and [next](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html).

Comment: arguably it is the most difficult but irritatingly it is also the must intuitively and direct to what we think the definitions "mean".  Intuitively $b^n$ is b multiplied by itself n times so "obviously" $b^{n/m}$ is the m-th root of b to the n and as x = lim q then $b^x$ is the limit of $b^q$.  I mean "duh" and obviously d(b^x)/dx = $C_b*b^x$ so there must be some $e$ where $C_e = 1$ and obviously $e^x$ means $e^x$ and $\ln x$ is just a logarithm.  That's obviously what it all "means".  It's a pity this is the freaking *hardest* approach.

Comment: @fleablood: as I say in my blog post "the most intuitive and obvious approach".

Comment: That's a nice blog post btw.

Answer (score 1):

$b^x$ can be defined as $\lim_{q\in \mathbb Q \rightarrow x}b^q$. (Isn't it usually so defined?)  Or alternatively one can define $e = \lim_{h\in \mathbb Q\rightarrow 0}\frac {x^h - 1}{h}$.

I think it's legit and not circular.

Comment: Of course, this assumes there is a limit.

Comment: It works; $b^q$ is defined for rational $q$ in the "usual" way, and you can force the limit to exist using a monotonicity argument. It is essentially the same argument that is used to prove that the only memoryless distributions, i.e. the ones with the property $P(X>t+s|X>t)=P(X>s)$, are the exponential distributions.

Comment: I think defining new notions of limit is bit complicated and non-standard. The standard calculus texts define limits of functions of real variable and limit of functions of integral variable (sequences). If $x_{n}$ is a sequence of rational numbers with limit $x$ then we can define $a^{x}$ as the limit of sequence $a^{x_{n}}$. The notion of $\lim_{x \in \mathbb{Q} \to a}$ can be made precise by an appropriate definition but it is not very commonly seen.

Comment: This isn't a new definition of limits at all.  For every real $x$ there is a rational sequence of {$q_n$}$\rightarrow x$ so we define $b^x$ as $\lim b^{q_n}$.  That's all my notation of $\lim_{q\in \mathbb Q\rightarrow x}$ means.  We do have to clear up that such a real sequence of {$b^{q_n}$} converges but that's pretty standard and mechanical as Ian points out.  (Actually it's a pain in the ass, but never mind...)

Comment: The actual difficulty is establishing the uniqueness: why is $\lim_n b^{q_n}$ the same for any given $q_n \to x$?

Comment: True.  It's a pain.  But it can be done. need to establish for any $\epsilon > 0$ then there are rational $r < q < t$ such $b^q - \epsilon < b^r < b^q < b^t < b^q + \epsilon$ (assuming $b > 1$; equivalent but "flipped" if 0< b < 1).  Then as all $q_n \rightarrow x$ all $b^{q_n}\rightarrow c$ for the same c.  No-one's saying it's not a pain.  But it is a *valid* consistent non-circular definition.

Comment: @Ian: if $q_{n}, r_{n}$ tend to $x$ then $s_{n} = q_{n} - r_{n} \to 0$ and we need to show that $b^{s_{n}} \to 1$. This is easy.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, though you don't even need to localize, you use the same monotonicity argument anywhere.