# $x(a^{1/x}-1)$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Prove that $f(x)=x(a^{1/x}-1)$ is decreasing on the positive $x$ axis for $a\geq 0$.

My Try:

I wanted to prove the first derivative is negative.

$\displaystyle f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x}a^{1/x}\ln a+a^{1/x}-1$. But it was very difficult to show this is negative. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Use the taylor expansion of $a^x - 1$.

Comment: Exclude $a=1$...

Comment: Taylor expansion around which point?

Comment: Around zero. With $a^x = e^{\ln(a) \cdot x} = 1 + \ln(a) \cdot x + ...$.

Comment: But I don't see how its useful. Here I have $a^{1/x}$, not $a^x$

Comment: @EpsilonDelta You can prove that $f(u)$ where $u=1/x$ is increasing instead, it's essentially the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is convex on $\mathbb R,$ then $(f(y) - f(0))/y$ increases as $y$ increases from $0.$ The function $y \to a^y$ is convex on $\mathbb R$ for any $a\ge 0.$ The result falls right out.

Comment: Just wondering: Why the down vote?

Comment: Welcome to the club of victims of unjustified downvotes ! Cheers.

Comment: Rough crowd.$\,\,$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $a\ne 0,1$, since $f$ is clearly decreasing for $x>0$ in these two cases.

Let $g(t)=a^t(1-t\ln a)$; then $g(0)=1$ and $g^{\prime}(t)=-a^t t(\ln a)^2<0$ for $t>0$, so $g(t)<1$ for $t>0$.

Letting $t=\frac{1}{x},\;\;$ $f^{\prime}(x)=a^{1/x}\left(1-\frac{\ln a}{x}\right)-1=a^t(1-t\ln a)-1=g(t)-1<0$ for $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

[Using simple algebra it is possible to prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1491888/72031) that $g(x) = f(1/x) = \dfrac{a^{x} - 1}{x}$ is strictly increasing for $x > 0, a > 0, a \neq 1$ and $x$ being rational. The extension to irrational values of $x$ is easily done by considering sequences of rationals converging to $x$.