# Where do we use continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

> If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $f'(0)=1$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$, show that $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Solution: It is clear that $f(0)=1$. For each $x$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\cdots=f(x)
\end{eqnarray}Hence, $f'(x)=f(x)$

*My question*: Where we use the continuity? Is it not enough that the function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You are only provided that $f$ is continuous, you cannot assume the limit exists.

Comment: the limit exists becuase $f'(0)$ exists

Comment: Hint: use the conditions provided to explicitly find what $f(x) $ is.

Comment: No, the limit does not need exist for point $x$. For $f'(0)$, the limit should be $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(h)-f(0)}h. $$

Comment: Notee that $x$ is fixed

Comment: I do not see that, could you tell me how you discovered it?

Comment: No, $x$ is not fixed. The full statement of your question needs some universal quantifiers sprinkled in appropriately. For example, the hypothesis should say that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ *for all* $x,y \in \mathbb R$. Also, the conclusion should say that $f'(x)=f(x)$ *for all* $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher I corrected it, thank you

Comment: Well, if $f$ is continuous at a (any) single point and $f(x) f(y) =f(x+y) $ then $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) =f'(0)f(x)$. So one can say that the existence of $f'$ at $0$ is redundant if one assumes continuity. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1885860/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, maybe you were right. I was assertive. If the continuity of $f$ is omitted, then for each $x$, $f(x+h)- f(x) = f(x)(f(h)- f(0)) \to 0 \cdot f(x) = 0 [h \to 0]$ since $f'(0)$ exists then $f$ is continuous at $0$, thus $f$ is still continuous everywhere.

Conclusion: $f \in \mathcal C (\mathbb R)$ is redundant.

Comment: Beat me to it by 6 hrs 59 minutes..................+1

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis

$$
\lim_{h\to0 }\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)=1.
$$

So, we use that $f$ is differentiable at $0.$ And we don't need more assumptions about continuity or differentiability.

First of all note that $f(0)=1.$ $f(0+0)=f(0)^2\implies f(0)=1$ or $f(0)=0.$ If $f(0)=0$ then $f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=0$ which contradicts the hypothesis $f'(0)=1.$

Now, using algebraic operations and that $f$ is differentiable at $0,$ we get
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0 }\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0 }\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)f(0)}{h}=f(x)\lim_{h\to0 }\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}.
$$

Comment: the question is: where we use the continuity of $f$

Comment: I have misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* need continuity for that. Since $f'(0)=1$, then, for each $x\in\mathbb R$,\begin{align}f'(x)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)f(h)-f(x)}h\\&=f(x)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-1}h\\&=f(x)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}h\\&=f(x)f'(0)\\&=f(x).\end{align}Note that $f(0)=f(0+0)=f^2(0)$ and that therefore $f(0)=0$ or $f(0)=1$. But you can't have $f(0)=0$, because otherwise$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=0$$and it would be false that $f'(0)=1$.