# Particular definition of e

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, definition, intuition

Show that, $$e=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x $$

Is the same number that satisfies, 
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h} = 1 \tag{*}$$

You don't have to do that if it's too cumbersome, but (*) is used to find the derivatives of real exponential functions. I know that definitions are not to be proven but I'm looking for some derivation or intution for the claim that (*) is a legitimate definition for e, and furthermore, a proof that limit in (*) exists.

Comment: You should have a look at this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1491888/72031 and the linked blogpost http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html where I deal with the limit of $(a^{x} -1)/x$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Comment: See Apostol book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the forward implication, given that $e = \lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + 1/x)^x$, we have for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}. $$

It s straightforward to show using Bernoulli's inequality that $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing and $(1 + 1/n)^{n+1}$ is decreasing.

Hence,

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \leqslant e \leqslant \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1},$$

and

$$1 \leqslant \frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n} \leqslant n\left[\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/n}- 1\right] =  (n+1)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/n}- n .$$

Using Bernoulli's inequality we have

$$(n+1)\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{1/n} - n  \leqslant (n+1) \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n}\right) - n  = 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Thus,

$$1 \leqslant  \frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n} \leqslant 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Applying the squeeze theorem we see that

$$\tag{*}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n} = 1.$$

Continuity and monotonicity of the exponential function $x \mapsto e^x$ can be used to show that (*) implies

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{h}-1}{h} = 1.$$

Comment: The nice bits of monotone magic :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Thanks.  Obviously a lot going on here to fill in the details for general continuous limits, so the reference to Paramanand Singh's blog is probably the best completion to the answer.

Comment: Although I have written a good number of posts on these things, your derivation for limit of $n(e^{1/n}-1)$ is new for me.  +1

Comment: BTW we can also use the inequality $(1+(1/n))^{n}\leq e\leq (1-(1/n))^{-n}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thank you.  I have certainly picked up more than a few nice tricks from your answers over time.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it would be very nice to have the contrary, so namely from $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$ to the $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$. Do you have the example somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

Consider a sequence $a_n$ that satisfies

$$\frac{(a_n)^{1/n}-1}{1/n}=1$$

It then follows that

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

And as $n\to\infty$...

(a bit of monotone magic may be in order)

Comment: You do need to add that "bit of monotone magic".

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I like the following procedure because it shows how to choose the '*best*' logaritm base $\ds{\mrm{a}}$: By '*best*' I mean the simplest $\ds{\log}$-derivative expression.

\begin{align}
\totald{\log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{x}}{x} & \stackrel{\mrm{def.}}{\equiv}
\lim_{h \to 0}{\log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{x + h} - \log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{x} \over h} =
\lim_{h \to 0}{1 \over h}\log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{1 + {h \over x}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over x}\log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{\lim_{h \to 0}\bracks{1 + {h \over x}}^{x/h}}
\end{align}
The '*simplest $\ds{\,\mrm{a}}$-choice*' is given by:
$$
\mrm{a} = \lim_{h \to 0}\pars{1 + {h \over x}}^{x/h} =
\lim_{n \to \pm\infty}\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{n} = \color{#f00}{\expo{}}
\quad\mbox{which yields}\quad
\totald{\log_{\,\mrm{a}}\pars{x}}{x} = {1 \over x}
$$