# How do you show $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} = 1$ when a = e?

Tags: calculus

This limit appears using the definition of a derivative applied to an exponential function. I understand the implications but I don't know how to show the basic result.

Comment: It depends on your definition of $e.$  Some people take the definition of $e$ to be the value of $a$ for which that limit equals $1$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3636700/lim-h-rightarrow-0-fracah-1h)