# Help with a proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{a^x-1}{x}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

I have found that proof

"Let $\underline{a>1}.$ I assume $a^x$ is continuous, and that the basic exponent law $a^{x+y}=a^xa^y$ holds.

Claim: $a^x$ is convex on $[0,\infty).$ Proof: Because $a^x$ is continuous, it suffices to show $a^x$ is midpoint convex. Suppose $x,y\in [0,\infty).$ Using $(uv)^{1/2} \le (u+v)/2$ for nonnegative $u,v,$ we get $a^{(x+y)/2} = (a^{x} a^{y})^{1/2} \le (a^x+a^y)/2.$

Now if $f$ is convex on $[0,\infty),$ then $(f(x)-f(0))/x$ is an increasing function of $x$ for $x\in(0,\infty).$ This is a simple and easily proved property of convex functions.

Claim: $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(a^x-1)/x$ exists. Proof: All of these quotients are bounded below by $0.$ As $x$ decreases to $0,(a^x-1)/x$ decreases by the above. Because of the lower bound of $0,$ the limit exists.

It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0}(a^x-1)/x$ exists. This follows from the above and the fact that if $x>0,$ then  $a^{-x} = 1/a^{x}.$ To handle $0<a<1,$ look at $[(1/a)^x-1]/x$ to see $\lim_{x\to 0}(a^x-1)/x$ exists."

source: [zhw](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/228045/zhw), Show $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(a^h-1)}{h}$ exists without l'Hôpital or even referencing $e$ or natural log, [URL (version: 2017-02-18)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491541)

Can someone please explain to me why in the first part a>1 is of relevance.

My second question is how can I use the last sentence to see that the special case delivers everything I want to have?

Answer (score 1):

you need $a >1$ for this part:

> Proof: All of these quotients are bounded below by 0.

For the last sequence:

Note:
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{a^h-1}{h}=-\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{a^{-t}-1}{t}=-\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1-a^t}{t}\frac{1}{a^t}=\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{a^t-1}{t}\frac{1}{a^t}$$

Finaly, if $a<1$ write $a=\frac{1}{b}$. Then $b>1$ and 
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b^h-1}{h}=-\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b^t-1}{t}\frac{1}{b^t}$$